# Installing PIP without root access

Tags: python, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux, pip

How do I install pip without root access?

---

**Specifically:**

I cannot `sudo`. When I do, I get `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

I ran `get-pip.py` and got the following error: `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1.dist-info'`

I am trying to do this on a basic Bluehost hosting plan. I have SSH access but no root.

The server is running Red Hat 4.4.7-17

Answer (score 0):

Use the --user flag to install pip for just the current user.

However, https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#id10 states:

> At this time, --user installs for pip itself, should not be considered
>   to be fully tested or endorsed.

---

**Specifically:**

Didn't work for me. If you don't have sudo, installing pip seems to be impossible.